# add a Static option with ng-options angularJS

Tags: angularjs

i ust use ng-options in a `select` element in angular js. and in `select` select i just wants to add a extra options at the beginning of options.my code ===>

```
<div class="form-group">
     <select class="form-control select2" ng-options="(o.fullName+' ('+o.email+')') for o in SubTeamUserList track by o.id" name="SelectedUserList" ng-model="SelectedUserList" multiple data-placeholder="Search By User" style="width: 100%;">
            <option value="" disabled>Select A User</option>
      </select>
</div>
```

[image]

that is not working for me ? i dont know why.then i search on net and found some solution like =>
[angularJS - add a Static option with ng-options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22312150/angularjs-add-a-static-option-with-ng-options)
[Add two extra options to a select list with ngOptions on it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30604938/add-two-extra-options-to-a-select-list-with-ngoptions-on-it)
[Angular ng-options - Is there a way to add an option when the model contains a value not present in the options list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28373770/angular-ng-options-is-there-a-way-to-add-an-option-when-the-model-contains-a-v)

after see above solutions i tried =>

```
     <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control select2" ng-options="" name="SelectedUserList" ng-model="SelectedUserList" multiple data-placeholder="Search By User" style="width: 100%;">
              <option value="" disabled>Select A User</option>
              <option ng-repeat="(o.fullName+' ('+o.email+')') for o in SubTeamUserList track by o.id">{{(o.fullName+' ('+o.email+')')}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

after doing this this is also showing something like =>
[image]
but that is also not working for me i dont know why? can anybody help me ???

Comment: please explain more detailed about `not working`.

Comment: I don't see any issue in this code: https://plnkr.co/edit/4DNPr7sR05S1V4eCbiKr?p=preview

Comment: I think you are missing syntext in ng repeat of option. its should be like : ng-repeat="o.SubTeamUserId as (o.fullName+' ('+o.email+')') for o in SubTeamUserList track by o.id"